# Run Java methods using shell (windows)

Tags: java, shell, cmd

I have a java class which includes a method called `kleiner`. I want to call it inside the shell (for example `kleiner 3 4`). Here is the code below:

```
package premier;

public class HelloWorld {
public static void kleiner(int a, int b) {
    if (a < b)
        System.out.println(a);
    else
        System.out.println(b);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Hello world");

    kleiner(3, 4);

}

}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Comment: That's what `args` is for in the main method. If you add `System.out.println(args)` and call `java HelloWorld 1 2` you'll get the idea of how it works

Comment: Can you use jshell?

Comment: If you run `java premier.HelloWorld`, the `kleiner` method *is* called with parameters `3` and `4`, so what is your question? Perhaps re-phrase question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps and you should able to run program from batch script.

1. Compile programm - `javac HelloWorld.java -d .`
   it will generate HelloWorld.class class file in package directory which can we invoke from command line.
2. run programm with `java premier.HelloWorld`

so if you put both the command in single bat file and click on the file. it will give output.

File name  - `HelloWorld.bat` copy these 2 lines in file content.

```
javac HelloWorld.java -d .
java premier.HelloWorld
```

Hope it will help you.